# program that takes a path to a file name as an argument (.txt file), reads the file and generates a new file that has every alternate line swapped

Tags: python, file

In the new file, line 2 is line 1 of original file, line 3 of new file is line 4 of original file, line 4 of new file is line 3 of original file so on.

example textfile1
line1
line2
line3
line4
'''

opening the file for reading

```
                      with open("test.txt", "r") as textfile1:       
                        content = file1.readlines()
```

creating a new file in write mode

```
                          with open("testswap.txt", "w+") as file2:      
                           for i in range(len(content)):
```

what logic should put here so in my new file  could save "line2" as first line , "line1" as 2nd line , "line3" as 4th line, and "line4" as 3rd line.

```
                            file2.write(content[i].replace("/n"," "))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you post the working code in a single block that we can run? Can you also rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```py
list1 = ["1 line",
         "2 line",
         "3 line",
         "4 line",
         "5 line",
         "6 line",
         "7 line"]



def swap_lines(list_object):
    for index, value in enumerate(list_object):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            continue
        else:
            list_object[index], list_object[index -1] = list_object[index-1], list_object[index]
    return list_object


for line in swap_lines(list1):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
2 line
1 line
4 line
3 line
6 line
5 line
7 line
```